# Is there a way to know if there is a cookie available before showing the SFAuthenticationSession prompt

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, ios11, sfauthenticationsession

On iOS 11, Apple introduced a new way to share auth data between the web and a Mobile App with `SFAuthenticationSession`.

It would be a bad user experience to show the `SFAuthenticationSession` prompt to every new users - that might have never used my website - to have them agree and then get nothing out of it and have ask them to login.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession) is pretty empty on Apple side. This is the only [example](https://github.com/dvdhpkns/SFAuthenticationSession-example) I found.

Is there a way to know if there is a cookie available **before** showing the `SFAuthenticationSession` prompt? Or maybe, with the `Associated Domains` enabled, when authenticating with my domain, the system should not show the prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Even if there aren't cookies, the user can login entering his username/password and then clicking on "Login"/"Enter" on the website (E.g: Facebook, Instagram).

Accessing the cookies won't be enabled:

> When the webpage is presented, it runs in a separate process, so the user and web service are guaranteed that the app has no way to gain access to the user’s credentials. Instead, the app gets a unique authentication token.
>   [Official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession)

Working example for Instagram-OAuth: https://github.com/dvdhpkns/SFAuthenticationSession-Instagram-Oauth

And the GitHub repo you added was posted by the author to send a bug report about errors in cookie sharing for local servers (rdar://33418129. [Original tweet](https://twitter.com/DVDHPKNS/status/887075910523826176))

> Are cookies shared between Safari and SFAuthenticationSession? 
>   @DVDHPKNS
>
> They’re supposed to be shared, but we have some timing bugs right now. Please do file bugs about what you’re seeing.
>   @rmondello (Apple employee)

P.S: They added more information to the docs since your original post date.

Comment: So does that mean that for now whenever SFAuthenticationSession is called an alert will be displayed ? and there is no way to avoid it ?

Comment: It's like a regular permission (E.g: Camera, Notifications, etc.) so there's no way to avoid it afaik since it's part of the authorization flow. From the docs: ` users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent`

Comment: Yes you are right but for camera and notifications etc it is a one time prompt. With SFAuthenticationSession though the prompt is displayed every time. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: No, you are right: SFAuthenticationSession  will require the user to accept each time.